# Enable Powerpoint Macro security (Enable all macros) without user interaction (Mac)

Tags: vba, shell, powerpoint

I need to enable all macros option without user interaction using VBA or shell script or using apple script?

Platform: Mac OSX

Please suggest any way to do this. My aim is to add powerpoint .ppam file to powerpoint without user interaction, I already adding ppam file using vba, but powerpoint throwing macro warning messages. I signed the ppam file using the digital signature, but still the Macros warning throwing.
Need help!!!!!
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't do that for security reasons. This is a security feature that no one can run code on a computer without permission! The only thing you can do is digitally signing the code with a certificate which is trusted by your users.

Comment: @Peh : Ok, Is any other way to avoid this warning alert? for example, securing ppam file kind of thing, I already did digital signature, but it's not helped to avoid alert

Comment: If the certificate is a self signed certificate it must be trusted in the trust center of office (see options) first to avoid the alerts. Other option is to get a signing certificate from a trusted authority (need to pay for this).

Comment: @Peh Trust center is not available in powerpoint 2016 Mac.

Comment: @Irshad my fault. But I guess then instead you would need to trust the certificate somewhere in MacOS, not trusted certificates will always issue an alert.

Comment: In Windows, you must sign the VBA project, not the PPTM file, in order for PowerPoint to allow the macros to run w/o user interaction. I don't think Mac PPT supports signing the VBA project, and in fact I notice from your screenshot that it lacks an option that's in the Win version:  "Disable all macros except digitally signed macros". That suggests that it doesn't support digitally signed macros.